SQL query help for data checking two tables in Snowflake
I have table A with column appleId.
I have table B with column bappleId.
Creating a row in table A should create a row in table B where appleId = bappleId.
Table A



Id
appleId




3
33


4
34


5
35


6
36



Table B Data



Id
bappleId




1
33


2
34



How can I query to make sure rows in table B were created? For example, I have 4 rows in table A and only 3 in table B means 2 rows are missing, but I also want the appleId, not just the count.
Expected output:
Something along the lines of 35, 36, which are the missing rows' appleId/bappleId in table B or even better would be 5, 6 since thats the id of the table A rows which did not get created in table B
Doing something like
select bappleId
from table b as b
where not exists  (select appleid from table a as a where a.appleId = b.bappleid)

returns only the extra rows in table B, not the missing ones in table A

You can use LEFT Join and a NULL condition
SELECT a.Id, a.appleId
FROM TableA a
LEFT JOIN TableB b ON a.appleId = b.bappleId
WHERE b.bappleId IS NULL;

Output


Using the Minus operator, the database will do the work for you.
select appleid as appleid from tablea
minus
select bappleid as appleid from tableb;

